# Laptop has internet but can't see network drives

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking

I have a home network with wifi, two wired computers (1 Win10 and 1 Linux that acts as server).

The linux machine has Shared Folders on it that I need to access.  My win10 Desktop can access the folders just fine.  My laptop however, can not.  Upon further investigation, while I do have internet, I can't ping the router (192.168.1.1).  I've read quite a few posts here and nothing quite fits.

I can ping google with relatively quick responses, I have complete internet access just can't ping the network computers (can't see them in win explorer either obviously).

I've turned off the laptops Firewall which is controlled by Norton 360.  I've also ensured that there are no IP conflicts (this computer is assigned 192.168.1.4 to ensure it didn't).  I've also turned off WiFi and plugged into the router but that doesn't change anything either... which I found extremely odd.

Interestingly, tracert shows that I go through 192.168.1.1 but I can't ping it?  Don't even have access to the routers settings through Firefox using the IP but I CAN do it on the desktop.

There's got to be a setting I'm overlooking on this computer but I can't figure it out.  Oh... I've also tried resetting the network in Network Settings ('Network Reset").

Below are some results from different CMDs in powershell.

**ipconfig /all**

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 04-ED-33-7A-3B-2D
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 06-ED-33-7A-3B-2C
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 04-ED-33-7A-3B-2C
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f5da:7f56:9bbd:ce8c%16(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, February 28, 2022 9:09:44 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, March 3, 2022 5:43:29 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 268758323
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-16-AC-28-04-D4-C4-E5-90-F6
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

**nbtstat -n**

Ethernet 2:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

```
No names in cache
```

Bluetooth Network Connection:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

```
No names in cache
```

Ethernet:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

```
No names in cache
```

Wi-Fi:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.4] Scope Id: []

```
            NetBIOS Local Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
ALIENROGLAPTOP <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered
ALIENROGLAPTOP <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
WORKGROUP      <1E>  GROUP       Registered
WORKGROUP      <1D>  UNIQUE      Registered
☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻<01>  GROUP       Registered
```

Local Area Connection* 9:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

```
No names in cache
```

Local Area Connection* 11:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

```
No names in cache
```

**ping 192.168.1.1**

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

**tracert [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**  (IP addresses removed other than local router)

Tracing route to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [142.250.191.100]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
2    10 ms    11 ms     9 ms
3    10 ms    10 ms     8 ms  static.midco.net
4    16 ms    16 ms    15 ms  static.midco.net
5    20 ms    19 ms    22 ms  static.midco.net
6    21 ms    20 ms    21 ms  static.midco.net
7    24 ms    22 ms    23 ms  static.midco.net
8    43 ms    40 ms    40 ms  static.midco.net
9    35 ms    39 ms    36 ms
10    41 ms    44 ms    41 ms
11    39 ms    48 ms    37 ms
12    38 ms    37 ms    38 ms

Trace complete.

**ping google.com**

Pinging google.com [172.217.0.174] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 172.217.0.174: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=116
Reply from 172.217.0.174: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=116
Reply from 172.217.0.174: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=116
Reply from 172.217.0.174: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=116

Ping statistics for 172.217.0.174:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 39ms, Maximum = 42ms, Average = 40ms

Comment: There are (to me) a lot of lines that are superfluous making it hard to ferret through. Is the Laptop NIC set for public networking? NiC adapter properties.  Is Network Discovery ON (for Private Networking)>?

Comment: System is set with Private Network, Network Discovery is on and File / Print Sharing is enabled.

I read in another post somewhere that some of these items were what others were asking for which is why I ran the CMDs and figured I'd provide... but yes, lots of information and I never found anything glaringly wrong.

Comment: Lets forget the Google and the router for a bit, what is the IP of the Linux machine (and which Linux distribution is it using? Ubuntu?). It has to be in the same 192.168.1 subnet as your Windows PC (you can check if "ifconfig" command, usually). If the IP address seems correct, you can check the firewall status with "ufw status" command on Ubuntu to see 445 and 139 ports (for SAMBA) are open.

Edit: also check that your neither computer is connected to the "WAN" port of your router (WAN and other ports usually can't see each other without setting changes in the router).

Comment: Yes it is Ubuntu 20.04.  IP for Linux is 192.168.1.11.  This is also a reserved IP I set in the router so that I could map drives using a static IP.  Samba ports are open (desktop can get to drives without issue) and is not on the WAN port.